# Ansible: How to define and call a global counter variable?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to create 2 increment counters, 1 for `count_pass` and 1 for `count_total`.
When `PASSED`, `count_pass` and `count_total` should `+1`. Whereas for `FAILED`, `count_total` should `+1`. I'm also trying to avoid using the `when` condition to fulfill this task.

```yaml
-
  name: CIS Requirements check
  hosts: target1
  vars:
    count_pass: 0
    count_total: 0
  serial: 1
  tasks:

    -
      name: Check for CIS PermitRootLogin
      lineinfile:
        path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
        #The string to search
        regexp: '^(\s*)PermitRootLogin(\s+)no(\s*)$'
        state: absent
      check_mode: yes
      register: permitrootlogin_check

    -
      debug:
        msg: "{% if permitrootlogin_check.changed %} [PASSED] SSH root login disabled { count_pass }} | {{count_total }} +1 {% else %} [FAILED] SSH root login not disabled {{ $
      register: permitrootlogin_results

    -
      name: Number of Compliant CIS Requirement
      debug:
        msg: "The number of compliant CIS requirement is {{ count_pass }} / {{ count_total}}"
```

However, the result is always 0.

```yaml
TASK [Number of Compliant CIS Requirement] *************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [target1] => {
    "msg": "The number of compliant CIS requirement is 0 / 0"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
target1                    : ok=17   changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Please refrain from posting the same question [multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73537131/ansible-playbook-based-on-condition-increase-count-print-message-and-append-t).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to implement programming paradigms which aren't plain possible, at least not in that way and since Ansible is not a programming language but a [Configuration Management Tool](https://www.ansible.com/use-cases/configuration-management) in which you declare a state. Therefore those are not recommended and should probably avoided.

I understand from your description that you try to implement a kind of Central/Global Node/Task Counter in a Distributed Environment. Please take note for the following example that it is an distributed system, with one (1) Control Node and two (2) Remote Nodes, whereby the tasks are executed remotely.

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    counter: 0

  tasks:

  # Check for CIS PermitRootLogin
  # task removed for focus on ...

  - name: Increase counter
    set_fact:
      counter: "{{ counter | default(0) | int + 1 }}"

  - name: Show counter
    delegate_to: localhost
    debug:
      var: counter
```

As one can see from the output

```yaml
TASK [Check for CIS PermitRootLogin] **********
ok: [test1.example.com]
ok: [test2.example.com]

TASK [Increase counter] ***********************
ok: [test1.example.com]
ok: [test2.example.com]

TASK [Show counter] ***************************
ok: [test1.example.com -> localhost] =>
  counter: '1'
ok: [test2.example.com -> localhost] =>
  counter: '1'

PLAY RECAP ************************************
test1.example.com : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
test2.example.com : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

the tasks become executed distributed. The counter becomes increased on each host for his own. Even delegating the output of the variable content back to the Control Node (`localhost`) will not end up in an aggregated result. It will still behave in the same manner if using `serial: 1`, except the output changes to tasks serial executed by host.

But there is already a counter for your task `Check for CIS PermitRootLogin` in the summary which reports it is not changed (`changed=0`) and therefore compliant.

**Further Q&A**

- [Ansible: Increment variable globally for all hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34254013/)
- [How to create global variable that each host in a play can read and write in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58139383/)

**Possible Soution**

Since the configuration status in question can be considered as `fact` you could probably use an approach with [discovering variables: facts and magic variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html), whereby [cachig facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#caching-facts) and [custom facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#adding-custom-facts) will be helpful. This will help to automatically keep track of hosts, configuration facts and compliance status.